# Can't Deploy Qt project from Qt Creator

Tags: qt, mingw

I am on Windows 7 and developing for windows desktop platform. I can't use the `Build --> Deploy Project` or `Build --> Deploy All` option. It is greyed out.

Qt Version 4.8.1 (Open Source Qt Libraries for MinGW)
Compiler - MinGW (gcc 4.4.0)
IDE - Qt Creator 2.7.1

What I want to achieve is a stand alone Windows Application. When I run it from the project debug directory, it runs fine. But When I remove Qt\bin from "Path", it gives **cannot find qtcore4.dll** .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "deploy" option is for deploying to devices (like mobiles). For creating a Windows executable, you need to ship the DLLs with it. Alternatively, you can build a static version of Qt and build a static executable.

More information:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html

Update: This has changed in Qt5. They do now offer a tool for Windows too. See:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html